# What is the difference between Mamba's condabin and bin directories

Tags: conda, mamba, mambaforge

I have just done a fresh install of mamba on a machine that does not have conda. However, I am able to run a mamba executable from 2 directories: - `~/mambaforge/condabin` and `~/mambaforge/bin`. Is there a reason to run mamba from on executable as opposed to the other?

Comment: Same as Conda's: it provides minimal surface to expose binaries globally. The `bin/` is for the **base** environment; the `condabin/` is always on PATH.

Comment: Thanks. But still: why?
What will happen if i set the bin/ folder in my path instead of the condabin?
Will something go wrong?